# how get PHP script to work as img source?

Tags: php, html, image-processing

I want to track some usage stats on email, and thought of putting the image that I use in a tracking script, and then add that to the email.

But, I can't get it to work. The code I have is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="test.php">
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code test.php:

```
  <?php
 // The image to return
$image=imagecreatefrompng("images/dl-front.png");

// ** Output image to browser
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagejpeg($image);

// ** Destroys the image
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

I'm getting the broken image link as shown below:

[image: output in browser]

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing how you're sending that email. The img source should contain an HTTP address. If it's local to you, then external resources won't be able to trigger it. Does error reporting show anything?

Comment: I was about to post an answer here, but thought I'd say this in comments. You're using an `.html` file here. Did you instruct your server to treat those as PHP? If not, it should hold an `.php` extension. Try that again. Or, maybe I'm wrong about this. You have 2 comments and now an answer below, see that. Ping me back if I'm not in the question anymore.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner No errors in the console. Im trying this first in the local envir.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` try adding that to the php file(s).

Comment: Nope. I think that .php script is only not getting called. What have i done wrong? Both html and php code reside in the same folder.

Comment: There may be an issue for the word "type" here for `header('Content-type: image/png');`. Try changing it to `header('Content-Type: image/png');` with a capital "T". I've seen that happen quite a few times.

Comment: I have tired that as well. From morning i'm trying to make this work. No luck

Comment: Try src=“/test.php” instead of src=“test.php”

Comment: @coders then `imagejpeg($image);` to `imagepng($image);` as per an example I took from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

Comment: @Pete i tired. Same result. Thanks

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner tired man. No result.

Comment: This might be a caching issue. If everything that you tried from suggestions, then I'm betting on that. I'd have to test it on my end but I won't have time to do that right now.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i have ran the same in the private browser. same issue

Comment: You should debug the test.php script first (make sure it works) by running it directly (http://localhost:8080/test.php). *Then* attempt to load it with an img tag. We can all keep guessing here but at some point you will have to investigate this yourself.

Comment: @Pete Do you think, I haven't tried all those things. When i try to run test.php, i will get below error   "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol".

Comment: I added the proper tags and echoed, then the image came

Comment: *"I added the proper tags and echoed, then the image came"* - Being what? I asked for errors earlier but you didn't tell us about that one above.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner This was long back man. before posting the question. When i directly try to call .php code in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer was given before the OP's edit https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51695324/1

I'm not sure, but you are creating a *.png*-image and then you are going to display this one using `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` so as a *.jpg*

So I think if you wanna display a *.png*-image you have to use
`header('Content-type: image/png');`

Comment: Where do you see `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` ?

Comment: Fair enough. I edited your answer in regards to that, just so everyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following PHP script to solve your problem:

```
$image = 'images/dl-front.png';
if(!file_exists($image)){
    die("File does not exist");
}
header('Content-Type:image/png');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($image));
header('Content-disposition: filename="dl-front.png"');
readfile($image);
```

Comment: Apologies for the typo. Make sure the image file exist. Works for me now.

Comment: No bro. Not working for me. Could let me know how are you calling from html page

Comment: I have added `header('Content-disposition: filename="dl-front.png"');` in the `PHP` script. It is now working using `HTML` tag `<img src="script.php" width="100" />`

Comment: @AhmedNumaan neither should be necessary

Comment: @WalterTross I thought the same but it did not work without that on my end.

Comment: @WalterTross `width` is not required. `header('Content-disposition: filename="dl-front.png"');` was missing.

Comment: @coders What do you see when you open `test.php` in browser? Like for example `http://localhost/project/test.php`

Comment: @AhmedNumaan The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: When you set the header of a particular file type which is image in our case, there's no need of character encoding in `PHP` script. Character encoding of an `HTML` document is different thing.

Comment: @WalterTross there is no white space. How can i check whether browser receives header or not